# AS3 Issues: Using a button to call a specific label frame on another movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to figure out how to make it so I can click a button on the main timeline and have it jump to a frame inside a separate movieclip on the main timeline.  This is the goofy code I have at the moment, but this is after a lot of changes, so who knows where I am right now.  This is for a simple virtual pet game and I'm not sure why I'm having such a hard time with this particular issue.  I'm missing something big.

```
function Shower(event:MouseEvent):void {
MovieClip(this.Egg).gotoAndPlay("shower");
}

// buttons
clean_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Shower);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're writing this on the Timeline, and not in a class. You don't need `MovieClip(this.Egg)` to access the movieclip you're trying to play. Instead, it should have an Instance Name (for example, "my_mc"), and you can just call it like this:

```
function Shower(event:MouseEvent):void {
    my_mc.gotoAndPlay("shower");
}

// buttons
clean_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Shower);
```

Comment: That did it.  A stupid mistake, but I never would have seen it myself without your answer! :D

Comment: Great! I'd appreciate it if you could just mark my answer as Accepted then.